# How do I specify a different view template for Anchor categories?

Tags: category-products, product-view

I need different views for my categories and anchor categories, so far I have this in my local.xml which seems to kind of work, but shows no products [there are products in the categories]

```
<catalog_category_layered>

   <reference name="content">
       <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view_2.phtml"/>
   </reference>

</catalog_category_layered>
```

this also loads the `view_2.phtml` twice.

how do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, just a small tweak. Since the block already exists no reason to define it again. Just update it.

```
<catalog_category_layered>

    <reference name="content">
         <reference name="category.products">
             <action method="setTemplate"><file>catalog/category/view_2.phtml</file></action>
         </reference>
    </reference>

</catalog_category_layered>
```